# bash - assigning output of find to variable while looping through list

Tags: bash, shell, variables, find, glob

I'm new to shell scripting. In bash, I'm trying to assign the output of find to a new variable while looping through a list.

```
for i in {25,27}; do
     r1=$(find $i*R1_001.fastq.gz)
     r2=$(find $i*R2_001.fastq.gz)
done
```

What I want to happen is for the compute to assign a file name to r1 and r2. For instance:

$ echo $r1

> 25-NVB206M02_S27_R1_001.fastq.gz

However, the computer interprets this as if the * is not a wildcard. I get an error that states:

**find: `25*R1_001.fastq.gz': No such file or directory**

Thank you for any advice you can provide.

Comment: Check the find man page. The first parameter of find is the folder where to start the search.

Comment: BTW, you are probably interested in `r1=$i*R1_001.fastq.gz`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use find you need something like:

```
r1=$(find . -name "${i}*R1_001.fastq.gz" | sed 's#^.*/##')
```

or, better, you can use:

```
r1="${i}*R1_001.fastq.gz"
```

Be aware that you may match 0 or more files with this. If multiple files match, for instance, if `i=2` then `r1` and `r2` would match `2-NVB...`, `20-NVB...`, `21-NVB...`, `200-NVB...`, and so on. You probably are only expecting the variable to hold a single file name. Try to tighten up what you are matching on.

If no files match `r1/r2` may still be not empty. Example:

```
(pi19 692) $ ls "*foo*"
ls: *foo*: No such file or directory
(pi19 693) $ r1="*foo*"
(pi19 694) $ echo $r1
*foo*
```